How to get the correct process with GetObject?
My workplace has both CATIA v5 and CATIA 3DExperience installed on the remote servers so I cannot directly add the COM reference and I have to use GetOject(,"CATIA.Application") to develop macros for CATIA.  It is okay for most of the time, however, is it possible to get the correct V5 if the macro is intended for V5 and 3Dx if a macro is intended for 3Dx?  The issue is that both V5 and 3Dx process is named as CATIA

I don't know anything about CATIA specifically, but if they're following the rules, there ought to be versioning on CATIA.Application so that you can request a specific version of it.  Your syntax looks like VBA rather than .NET, can you confirm which VB you're using?

@Craig, VB.NET - the GetObject usage can be the same between VBA and VB.NET. I can check if the CATIA is V5 to V6  - the issue is that I will always get the first that is opened - how can I loop through what is being opened and get the correct one?

I'm not sure whether you're trying to get a specific version of it, or if you're trying to identify the version of the running instance.  Can you clarify?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934746/is-it-possible-to-target-specific-com-instances-of-catia
